# How do you access items from an SQLAlchemy many-to-many relationship using Python?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

My many-to-many model looks like this, with an association table:

```
class Puppy(Base):
    __tablename__ = "puppy"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    name = Column(String(80))

class Adopter(Base):
    __tablename__ = "adopter"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    name = Column(String)
    puppies = relationship('Puppy', secondary='puppy_adopters', backref="puppy")

puppy_adopters = Table('puppy_adopters', Base.metadata,
                       Column('puppy_id', Integer, ForeignKey('puppy.id')),
                       Column('adopter_id', Integer, ForeignKey('adopter.id')))
```

If I have created an Adopter named Bill, I can easily add and retrieve his puppies with Python:

```
bill.puppies.append(fido)
bill.puppies.append(rex)
for puppy in bill.puppies:
    print puppy.name     # Fido, Rex
```

The `puppy_adopters` association table is populated with Bill's id and Fido's id when I do this. But how do I see that Bill is related to Fido, using Python? I get a Python object for Fido using `fido = session.query(Puppy).filter_by(name="Fido")`, but there is no `fido.adopters` list that contains Bill. How can I see all the people that have adopted Fido?

I tried this line in the puppy table:

```
adopter_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('adopter.id'))
```

but it did not get populated when I added an adopter, and it couldn't hold multiple adopters anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQLAlchemy docs provide what you need under their [Many to Many](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many) section. What you are looking for is `back_populates`.

```
class Puppy(Base):
    __tablename__ = "puppy"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    name = Column(String(80))
    adopters = relationship('Adopter',
        secondary="puppy_adopters",
        back_populates="puppies")

class Adopter(Base):
    __tablename__ = "adopter"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    name = Column(String)
    puppies = relationship('Puppy',
        secondary="puppy_adopters",
        back_populates="adopters")

puppy_adopters = Table('puppy_adopters', Base.metadata,
                       Column('puppy_id', Integer, ForeignKey('puppy.id')),
                       Column('adopter_id', Integer, ForeignKey('adopter.id')))

Rex = Puppy(name='Rex')
Fido = Puppy(name='Fido')
Bob = Adopter(name='Bob')
Steve = Adopter(name='Steve')

Steve.puppies.append(Fido)
Bob.puppies.append(Fido)
Bob.puppies.append(Rex)
print [adopter.name for adopter in Fido.adopters] # ['Steve', 'Bob']
print [puppy.name for puppy in Bob.puppies] # ['Fido', 'Rex']
```

Comment: I had been using `backref`, and the docs you mention refer to it as an alternative to `back_populates`, so I didn't try changing that. It does work. Is something wrong in the docs? I feel like their third code sample under [many to many](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many) should have a `parents` relationship, just as the `back_populates` example above it does. When I add one, the code works as well as yours.